# how to validate unique property in asp net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

How to check if the name already exists or not

```
    public class Test
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Number { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Where would the name exist?

Comment: Some would argue, that this it's the wrong place: Model validation should ensure valid data but this is business logic. It's often done this way: 1. create model (and validate it) 2. Check if you're allowed to save it (name must be unique) 3. Try save but create an index on the name field so save would fail if name already exists.

Comment: Thanks very much. The name list exists in the database (SQL Server ).

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could write a custom validate attribute to check this. Like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Base.Models;

 
public class NameUserUniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _IdPropertyName;
    public NameUserUniqueAttribute(string IdPropertyName)
    {
        _IdPropertyName = IdPropertyName;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string name = value.ToString();
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_IdPropertyName);
        if (property != null)
        {
            var idValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            var _context = (AppDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(AppDbContext));
            var entity = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Name == value.ToString() && e.Id != idValue);

            if (entity != null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(value.ToString()));
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return $"Name {name} is already in use.";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [NameUserUnique(nameof(Id))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it working correctly. But, it can't update the edit action.

When trying to edit the existing data it shows name already in use

Comment: I think you could also check the ID value. If the id is not exists and the name is exists then it will return false. More details, you could refer to my update answer.